# How to Apply Reverse Logic for Decoding?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, decode, decoding

I'm on the last part of a decoding Python exercise, and this is really confusing me. The encoding represents the 376th  to  65912th word with three chars: the  first   char is always (0xFA),  the second  is  ((code  - 376)  //  256),   and third   is  ((code  - 376)  %   256).    **For  example,    if  the code    is  30000,  then    the first   output  char    would   be  0xFA,   the 
second  0x73,   and the third   0xB8.   (The    code    for 376 would   be  FA  00  00.)**

Now here's my confusion, how can I interpret 0xfa 0x73 0xb8 as 30000? Because this word would be the 30000th word for my dictionary. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So the first element (`0xFA`) doesn't serve any purpose for re-calculating `code`?  Since it's not based off `code`?

Comment: @jedwards That's right, 0xFA does not serve any purpose for re-calculating the code.

Comment: Can the original `code` value ever be less than 376?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the first char, if it is 0xFA, then

`code = second * 256 + third + 376`

Answer (score 1):

```
get_code = lambda c: int(c[1], 16)*256 + int(c[2], 16) + 376

chars = ('0xFA', '0x73', '0xB8')
print get_code(chars)
```